# Convert OpenLayers.Map to XML

Tags: javascript, xml, openlayers

I have a Openlayer map with multiple layers.
I want to convert this map to XML (OWS Format). The goal is to allow the user to download / upload a context.

In documentation I found : 
http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/OWSContext-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.OWSContext.toContext method which takes an OpenLayer.Map as input and gives an context object as output.

Then I found http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/Context-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.Context.write that takes a context as input and gives a context document string.

I don't understand how I can work with these 2 methods to get an XML string as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var owc = new OpenLayers.Format.OWSContext();
var output = owc.write(olmap, {id: 'foo'});
```

Works fine, I had a dummy fake layer that caused a bug.